# Counterexample and condition to be true of this proposition

Tags: calculus

Let $f\left(x\right)$ be differentiable on interval $\left(a,b\right)$ and $f'\left(x\right)>0$ on that interval. If $\underset{x\rightarrow a+}{\lim}f\left(x\right)=0$, $f\left(x\right)>0$ on that interval?

I think this proposition is true by my intuitive, but I wonder whether intuitive is mathematically and strictly true and what condition to be add to be true. I can't believe my intuition, due to possiblilty of flaw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a consequence of mean value theorem. Redefine $f$ at $a$ by $f(a) =0$ so that $f$ is continuous on $[a, b) $. If $x\in(a, b) $ then we have  via mean value theorem $$f(x) =f(a) +(x-a) f'(c_{x} )>0$$ where $c_{x} $ is some point in $(a, x) $ depending on $x$.

Answer (score 1):

By Taylor's theorem (upto first order), for any $x\in(a+\epsilon,b)$, $\exists \zeta\in(a+\epsilon,b)$
$$f(x)=f(a+\epsilon)+(x-a-\epsilon)f'(\zeta) $$

Since $f'(\zeta)>0$, and $x>a+\epsilon$, this shows that $f(x)>f(a+\epsilon)$.

Now take the limit $\epsilon\rightarrow0^+$ to get that $f(x)>\lim_{\epsilon\to 0^+}f(a+\epsilon)=\lim_{x\to a^+}f(x)=0$, i.e. $f(x)>0$, $\forall x\in(a,b)$.

Comment: Taking limit weakens the inequalities. You need a minor change to fix this issue.